# Why does my application close when I click it in the Fluxbox Iconbar(?)?

Tags: linux, debian, fluxbox

This is really about finding the correct setting. When I click on an icon on the iconbar (the part of the toolbar that holds active window tabs? I'm not even sure I know the correct terms for the parts of the window manager) if it does not have the focus, it gets the focus (no problem so far), but if it already has the focus it closes the window. I'd love to change this behavior.

If I click here stackexchange will close:
[image]

EDIT: This behavior happens on my desktop but not on my laptop. While there are many differences between the two installs, whatever the problem is it's not inherent to all flux installs. Also there is nothing in the logs (I thought that maybe it's a bug or missing package problem on my machine).

EDIT2: @filipe-brandenburger had the right idea but not the correct file. I painfully disabled files and rebooted, checked , and repeated the process until I found the problem line in my `.fluxbox/init` file. Specifically there is a line

```
session.screen0.iconbar.mode:   {static groups} (minimized=no) (Workspace)
```

which when commented out solves my problem. However, I would still like to understand what this line intends to do as it's not clear to me why this causes my windows to close in that way.

EDIT3: Changing the line to

```
session.screen0.iconbar.mode:   Workspace
```

as outlined as one of the valid options solves the problem. If someone comes along to explain what happened I'll add some bounty.

Comment: Do you mean _close_? Or _minimize_?

Comment: Yup, I really mean close.

Comment: Did you try to rename (or delete) `~/.fluxbox` to have a fresh start?

Comment: @mviereck that does seem to fix it so it seems like a misconfiguration or a setting and not a bug; just need to find which one.

Answer (score 0):

The mouse settings are configured in your `~/.fluxbox/keys`

Mouse button clicks map to "keys" named such as `Mouse1`, `Mouse2`, `Mouse3`, etc. for left-click, right-click, middle-click and so on.

There are also modifiers such as `OnToolbar`, `OnTitlebar` or `OnTab` for when you click one of those elements. (Looks like `OnTab` might be the one you want?)

So take a look at your `~/.fluxbox/keys` and see if you find an event for `OnTab Mouse1` that looks suspicious...

Considering you have one machine that works and one that doesn't, comparing those two might give you a hint of what might be wrong...